# Static DIV on Right, Fluid (width) DIV on left taking up remaining space with 'sticky' DIV trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I hope I can explain this correctly as it sorta involves two effects/aspects.

I have (sorta) been able to do either.. but not BOTH together..

**Summary:**
I have a member directory, where I list out a bunch of 'entries' (results) based on the (proximity) search...

I have these entries (DIV's) all listed/displayed in a container DIV
I have a Google map on the RIGHT, which plots markers matching the entries on the left.

**Goal:**

Part I:
I want the static width MAP CONTAINER to be positioned right...
I want the search results (container) to be be positioned left.. but I want the width to take up whatever room is left up until the MAP CONTAINER DIV..

I have done that already...
Fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/VHcPT/352/

Part II:
Before I attempted to add in the above behavior...  I had the map container be a 'sticky' map..  which means that it is positioned where it is on page load/default.. but when you scroll to a certain position... the map will them become 'sticky' and scroll along (down) with the user as they scroll through all the search results..

This was working fairly decent... (unless there was only 2-3 results...and made the map 'jump')...

However.. and after implementing the results container to 100% width to take up the space up to the map container...

Once the map becomes 'sticky' the left (results) container goes ABOVE the map container.. and goes full width...

JS code I'm using for my 'sticky' map behavior:

```
//sticky map placement
$(function(){
    var stickyMapTop = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;  
    var stickyMapBottom = ($('#directory').offset().top + $('#directory').outerHeight())  - ($('#mapContainer').outerHeight(true));
    var directoryBottom = stickyMapBottom - stickyMapTop + (parseInt($('#mapContainer').css("marginTop").replace('px', '')));

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        if(viewportWidth > 768){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyMapTop && $(window).scrollTop() < stickyMapBottom) {
                $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', left: $('#mapContainer').offset().left});
            }else{
                if($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyMapBottom) {
                    //secondary position check to see what new positioning style to apply?  
                    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'relative', top: directoryBottom, left:'0px'});
                }else if($(window).scrollTop() < stickyMapTop){ 
                    //needed?
                    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                }
            }
        }else{
            $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

I'm assuming its because at a certain point to make the map sticky, I make it 'fixed' which takes it out of the DOM so to speak? and it isnt being respected/seen by other elements?

Have can I get BOTH to work?

example (live) URL to check out:  (please read comment below to understand)

** URL Removed as thread seems dead.  :)

**** replace the ### with a . in the url.**

Comment: can you post an example were you implement the "sticky" map behavior? - To answer the question of whether you can have "BOTH" work?  the answer is yes.

Comment: I 'sorta' have a live example for you to look at, (post link in main post)

When the page loads.. use FireBug to find the styles applied to the 'directory' (ID).  Remove the style of: width:74.5%   

Then once you scroll, you will see how the left container/search results go 'full width' and overlap (on top) the map container element.

Comment: You wont really be able to test the 'fluid' aspect of the search results container in its current state.. (as the site itself doesnt have responsive/breakpoints set up.. until about 768px wide or so...  and under that I move the map tot he top anyways.. so the 100% width taking up space up to the map container is no longer an issue/concern.  (hope that makes sense)

Comment: It's going to be hard to give a good answer without an example of the behavior that is causing issue; really one can only guess. Like @HelmutGranda said, this is very possible.

Comment: URL was removed.. since nobody responded for months.